# SaltStack: Why run master as daemon

Tags: amazon-web-services, salt-stack

I'm starting to look into Salt for server provisioning on AWS. I know that you can setup the servers as masterless or master/minion. If I use a master, I can understand why I'd run the minion as a daemon but I can't understand why I'd run the master as a daemon.

As I understand it, the master would push changes to the minions. So unless the minions need to regularly communicate with master to basically check in, couldn't I just run the salt-master when I need to provision a new server or push changes to the servers I need to change?

The servers that are getting provisioned are production web servers so I can't have them restarting services at will, I need to control when they do that (hopefully never).

Comment: normally service is reloaded (not restarted), your application didn't get impacted. Second, if you have hundreds or thousand servers, you need daemon on master to serve the incoming request.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying that issuing a service restart does not impact it's ability to handle request. My experience with mysql is different. The mysql server must stop then start when ever a restart command is issued. During this time it will not be able to process requests.